# Why an offset is calculated as $(2^{n-1} - 1)$ instead of $\,2^{n-1}\, $ for floating point?

Tags: computer-science, binary

This question is not about `two's complement`, it's about `offset binary`.

I'm trying to understand why offset `K` in binary offset notation is calculated as 
$2^{n-1}-1$ instead of $2^{n-1}$ in the IEEE-754 floating point exponent represenation. Here is my reasoning for $2^{n-1}$.

Four bits can represent values in the range $[-8;7]$, so $0000$ represents $-8$. An offset from zero here is $8$ and can be calculated as $2^{n-1}$. Using this offset we can define representation of any number, for example, the number $3$.

What number do we need to add to $-8$ to get $3$? It's $11$, so $3$ in offset binary is represented as $1011$. And the formula seems to be `number to represent` + `offset`.

However, the formula in a floating point calculation is `number to represent` + `offset` - $1$, and so the correct representation is $1010$. Can someone please explain why we also subtract additional one?

Comment: That's not how bit representations usually work. Typically, the first 1 is a "sign bit", so that $0000$ represents $0$, $1111$ represents $-1$ and $0111$ represents $+7$.

Comment: are you sure, [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_binary) states the $0111$ is $-1$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If the first bit is the sign, then 1111 is usually 7 and 0111 is -1. (0 means negative, 1 means positive).

Comment: @AlexisOlson so, by the "typical representation", I mean [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Yeah, but your sign was not typical.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, this question is not about `two's complement`, it's about `offset binary` or `biased representation`.

Comment: @Maximus ah, I see that now.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Your Wiki article states *"there is no standard for offset binary, but most often the offset K for an n-bit binary word is $K = 2^{n−1}$"*.  Are you asking specifically about the application to floating point arithmetic?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, yes, you're right, thanks for pointing out that $(2^{n-1}−1)$ applies to floating point. I was confused why the article shows offset as $K=2^{n-1}$, while I calculated it as  $K=2^{n-1}-1$ for floating point